# Flutter - not able edit pubspec.yaml file

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add this in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_date_picker: "^0.1.8"
```

But I'm not able to update packages. I only get an error in Flutter after editing `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: This question is quite pointless without the exact and full error message.

Comment: Agreed! error is needed. Aside from that, for me it works fine like this : dependencies:
  flutter_date_picker: ^0.1.8

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intl: ^0.15.7 -->**Add Your dependencies like this at pubspec.yaml**
```